# HOWTO: Migrate SharePoint site from one farm to another?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I've a site deployed on a developed machine. The site was developed under `WSS 3.0` which contains custom `List`, `Features`, `Templates`, `Styles` etc.

What I've to do is to create a deployment package (setup) which I can give away to my client. I know about `stsadm` but I don't have the access of the production machine.

Is there a way I can package all the dependencies in a single file (installation file) and run on the server which will include all the dependencies (including site content)?

I've tried to experiment this with [SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard](http://www.codeplex.com/SPDeploymentWizard). It all went well when `Export` the site but always fail to `Import` with the following message:

```
[2/2/2010 3:43:25 PM]: Start Time: 2/2/2010 3:43:25 PM.
[2/2/2010 3:43:25 PM]: Progress: Initializing Import.
[2/2/2010 3:43:42 PM]: FatalError: Could not find WebTemplate #75805 with LCID 1033.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.VerifyWebTemplate(SPRequirementObject reqObj)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.Validate(SPRequirementObject reqObj)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.DeserializeAndValidate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.VerifyRequirements()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
[2/2/2010 3:43:48 PM]: Progress: Import Completed.
[2/2/2010 3:43:48 PM]: Finish Time: 2/2/2010 3:43:48 PM.
[2/2/2010 3:43:48 PM]: Completed with 0 warnings.
[2/2/2010 3:43:48 PM]: Completed with 1 errors.
[2/2/2010 3:44:51 PM]: Start Time: 2/2/2010 3:44:51 PM.
[2/2/2010 3:44:51 PM]: Progress: Initializing Import.
[2/2/2010 3:45:08 PM]: FatalError: Could not find WebTemplate #75805 with LCID 1033.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.VerifyWebTemplate(SPRequirementObject reqObj)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.Validate(SPRequirementObject reqObj)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.DeserializeAndValidate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.VerifyRequirements()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
[2/2/2010 3:45:14 PM]: Progress: Import Completed.
[2/2/2010 3:45:14 PM]: Finish Time: 2/2/2010 3:45:14 PM.
[2/2/2010 3:45:14 PM]: Completed with 0 warnings.
[2/2/2010 3:45:14 PM]: Completed with 1 errors.
[2/2/2010 3:56:17 PM]: Start Time: 2/2/2010 3:56:17 PM.
[2/2/2010 3:56:17 PM]: Progress: Initializing Import.
[2/2/2010 3:56:34 PM]: FatalError: Could not find WebTemplate #75805 with LCID 1033.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.VerifyWebTemplate(SPRequirementObject reqObj)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.Validate(SPRequirementObject reqObj)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.DeserializeAndValidate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.VerifyRequirements()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
[2/2/2010 3:56:39 PM]: Progress: Import Completed.
[2/2/2010 3:56:39 PM]: Finish Time: 2/2/2010 3:56:39 PM.
[2/2/2010 3:56:39 PM]: Completed with 0 warnings.
[2/2/2010 3:56:39 PM]: Completed with 1 errors.
```

I actually couldn't find a good reference on how to use it. But, this software doesn't something I'm looking for which can create a simple deployment package (after that you don't need to do anything). I might not be correct but after two days of googling I think there is no such utility (freeware) that can create a simple package of a site and install on other farm without even need to configure anything before you run the installation package.

You people might have an advise which can help me to look/think outside the box and get to the solution quickly instead adding more days working on the problem.

***Please, share only freewares. I can't afford to buy anything.***

I'm waiting to be surprised with a good share :)

Have a good day!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have a solution grouping all those features, [SharePoint Installer](http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller) will deploy them to you in the next-next-finish way, and depending on the scope of the features they need to be activated thru the Manage Features web interface inside the Site Collection / Web.

Comment: How can i group all the dependencies of the sharepoint site and developed a wsp file contains the complete package of the site (ready to deploy)?

Comment: Short Answer is WSPBuilder (http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder) if you have Visual Studio it will be much easier ( http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/features/article.php/3849011/Developing-SharePoint-Solutions-in-Visual-Studio-Using-WSPBuilder.htm and http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2009/04/08/wspbuilder-walkthrough-of-the-visual-studio-add-in.aspx ), if you dont here's the command line: http://sharepointcoding.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/wspbuilder-correct-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

There is no silver bullet to this. If you migrate from server A to B you'll have to do an inventory on what is installed on server A and provision that on server B. You can look at what Solutions are installed on Central Administration, what webparts are available in the site, what software is installed on the server, etc.

This error regarding WebTemplate #75805 is caused by your target server not having a custom template. Most likely your target server is missing the fantastic 40 or so, download [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb407286.aspx). There is no way to be sure since anyone can use those numbers but it seems to be the "[JRIM JobRequisition](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B193C98B-562E-43DF-9EDF-25C674A9CA90&displaylang=en)" template.